# Is there a way to use Steam Cloud saves and actually save progress?

Tags: steam-cloud, shantae-half-genie-hero

It seems like only the saves in this location can be overwritten by the game:

```
%APPDATA%\Wayforward\ShantaeHeroUltimate\
```

But the game itself prioritizes the saves in this location, which are never overwritten by the game:

```
<Steam-folder>\userdata\<user-id>\764300\remote\
```

So progress basically stalls at the files in the second location.

Is there a way to both save progress to Steam Cloud and progress the game? I'm fine with using batch commands and Launch Options if I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`mklink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) command to create [a symbolic link, a hard link, or a junction](https://devtidbits.com/2009/09/07/windows-file-junctions-symbolic-links-and-hard-links/) pointing to the Steam Cloud folder.

1. Make a backup of your saves from `%APPDATA%\Wayforward\ShantaeHeroUltimate\`
2. Delete the `%APPDATA%\Wayforward\ShantaeHeroUltimate\` folder.
3. Make a link pointing to the Steam Cloud folder (choose **only 1** option). To be safe, I recommend using absolute paths instead of relative ones:

   - Symbolic link (haven't tested it with the Steam Cloud):
     `mklink /d %APPDATA%\Wayforward\ShantaeHeroUltimate\ <Steam-folder>\userdata\<user-id>\764300\remote\`
   - Hard link (only works if both folders are on the same partition, e.g. both are on `C:\`):
     `mklink /h %APPDATA%\Wayforward\ShantaeHeroUltimate\ <Steam-folder>\userdata\<user-id>\764300\remote\`
   - Junction (tested and works with Metal Gear Rising Revengeance):
     `mklink /j %APPDATA%\Wayforward\ShantaeHeroUltimate\ <Steam-folder>\userdata\<user-id>\764300\remote\`
4. Launch the game and look inside the `<Steam-folder>\userdata\<user-id>\764300\remote\` to see if a new savegame was created.

   - If no new savegame was created, play until you reach a point where you're absolutely certain a savegame should've been created.
5. Once you've confirmed that the link is working, it's time to restore your backup. Make sure that the game is running and not in a state where it will write save files (e.g. the game is currently on the title screen).
6. Copy your backup into the `<Steam-folder>\userdata\<user-id>\764300\remote\` folder and overwrite any existing files already inside.
7. Use the Task Manager to kill the game, just to be sure the game won't try to overwrite your savegames as it tries to exit. Once the game is no longer running, Steam should upload your saves to the cloud.
8. Launch the game again and verify that your saves have been restored properly.
9. Once you've confirmed that your saves are properly working, you may delete the backup.

The reason for this slightly convoluted process is because there's a risk Steam will overwrite saves that weren't created or modified while the game was running.

**Warning**: Do be careful when making links, as it can cause problems with anti virus softwares, backup softwares, or other apps that scan through the filesystem. For example, if you have a folder structure like `A/B/C` and `C` is a link that points to `B` (or to `A`), you will have created a cycle, which may cause an infinite loop in the aforementioned apps (possibly crashing them in the process). The same can happen in the case of `A/B/C` and `A/Y/Z` where `C` points to `Y` and `Z` points to `B`. This has happened to me before.

Comment: Junction does work! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, needs to Junction from Remote to ShantaeHeroUltimate, but Junction was right. Not sure how to get "<user-id>" to be properly preceeded by a "\" here. Markdown issues?

Comment: @Malady, I think that's because the backslash is an escape character. When you write `<bla>`, it is interpreted as an HTML tag and not displayed. To display it, you need to escape the opening bracket like this: `\<bla>`. And of course, if you want a backslash to be rendered as a character, you need to escape it as well (a double backslash will render as a single one). Alternatively, you can use a [code block](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax#code) to avoid escaping backslashes.